# Python csv new line character in field

Tags: python, csv

I am having an issue reading a thorn-delimited csv file that I think has a new line character in one of the fields. It is forcing the row over two lines so I cannot read the values in the last fields of the row. I have tried opening in `new line mode` but not sure what the best way of going about this is.

This is how I am trying to read the file in `python`:

```
csv.register_dialect('BB', delimiter='\xfe')
with open(file, 'rU') as file_in: 
    log=csv.reader(file_in, dialect='BB')
    for row in log:
        print row
```

This works fine for most of the file but there is a row that I assume has a new line character in one of the fields - i'm not sure best how to diagnose it. This is a screenshot of how the row looks in notepad, as you can see it forces the row on two lines when it should look like the two rows below.
[image]

Reading this with `csv.reader` the row looks like this:

['06-13-2015-10:13:41', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '142', '', '5', '7.0', '2', '', 'cmhkl966', 'amex_674', '1', '0.00', '', '', "' "]

i.e. truncated at that first apostrophe.

Comment: this is not the first time i see `þ` as a csv separator. is there a reason for that? is there an application that defaults to this separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i stripped down your problem a bit (hope i captured the cause of the problem):

```
import io
import csv

file_in = io.StringIO('''
aþbþ'hello
world'
''')

log=csv.reader(file_in, delimiter='\xfe', quotechar="'")
for row in log:
    print(row)
```

output:

```
['a', 'b', 'hello\nworld']
```

---

**UPDATE:**

as requested in the comments: here a version where the `.csv` is read from a file. the contents of `test.csv` are:

```
aþbþ'hello
world'þc
dþeþ'hello
other
things'þf
gþhþiþj
```

and the python code:

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

HERE = Path(__file__).parent
DATA_PATH = HERE / '../data/test.csv'

with DATA_PATH.open('rU') as file_in:
    log=csv.reader(file_in, delimiter='\xfe', quotechar="'")
    for row in log:
        print(row)
```

which outputs:

```
['a', 'b', 'hello\nworld', 'c']
['d', 'e', 'hello\nother\nthings', 'f']
['g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Comment: Can you also show a demo of same method when reading from a file , instead of StringIO ?

Comment: thanks for pointing out that things could go wrong there. updated.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I thought the solution might involve the quoting but I wasn't sure how it should be approached.

Comment: How would you solve the issue if you are to write a csv with a new line in afield ?

Comment: @romainjouin haven't tried, but reversing the process above (starting from the lists and writing them) should work. does it not?

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively check whether the first element of the next row starts with a timestamp and if not, use the list `extend` function to add it to the contents of current row before printing.

Disclaimer: Not tested

```
import re

csv.register_dialect('BB', delimiter='\xfe')
with open(file, 'rU') as file_in: 
    log=csv.reader(file_in, dialect='BB')
    for i in range(0, len(log) - 1):
        if re.search('\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+:\d+:\d+', log[i+1][0]) is None:
            i.extend(log[i+1])
        print i
```

Comment: Thanks - i agree, I think this would solve it also but I have accepted hiro's answer as it means less addition to the cost